# How can I terminate the program when I am not waiting for the child process in the parent?

Tags: c, fork, wait, kill, execvp

I am trying to make a program that mimics a Linux shell.

And it runs in two modes

(1) Interactive Mode (No arguments)

Wait for the child process. Execute one command at a time.

(2) Batch Mode (Given A file)

Do not wait. Try to execute the commands in parallel.

My code is pretty long so I decided to make a sample program to address (focus) on the problem that I am facing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct commands
{
    char *cmd[2];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("A program made to understand execvp\n");

    commands threeCommands[3];

    pid_t process;
    int child_status;

    threeCommands[0].cmd[0] = "date";
    threeCommands[0].cmd[1] =  NULL;

    threeCommands[1].cmd[0] = "pwd";
    threeCommands[1].cmd[1] =  NULL;

    threeCommands[2].cmd[0] = "cal";
    threeCommands[2].cmd[1] =  NULL;

    for(int i = 0;i <3;i++)
    {
        process = fork();

        if(process == 0)
        {
            execvp(threeCommands[i].cmd[0],threeCommands[i].cmd);
        }
        else
        {
             //wait(&child_status);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I am commenting out the wait so that I try to do concurrent processing and the results of the commands are randomized and maybe intermixed.

The problem is after the execution of the three commands `date,pwd,cal`

The program doesn't terminate. It freezes in this state and doesn't just end, so my cursor is there as if it needs input. And my program doesn't end. How can I fix this?

Should I use kill or what?

Answer (score 1):

Just press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after the output.

If the parent process exits before the child processes then the shell will print the prompt after the parent process exits, then the child processes prints their output but the shell won't print a new prompt. Look a few lines above the end of the output to see the prompt after the parent process exits.

For example, after modifying your code to add a `sleep(1)` before calling `execvp` (to force the child processes to be delayed) I get the following output on my system:

```
[~/tmp]$ ./a.out 
A program made to understand execvp
[~/tmp]$ tis  9 feb 2016 18:54:06 CET
/home/XXXX/tmp
   Februari 2016      
sö må ti on to fr lö  
    1  2  3  4  5  6  
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13  
14 15 16 17 18 19 20  
21 22 23 24 25 26 27  
28 29
```

As you see the prompt is printed before the `date` command runs (the `.[~/tmp]$` before the `date` output). Pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> brings the prompt back.

Comment: That's awesome, But how would I enter an enter key in my code ? So I don't need to do it manually

Comment: @Pro You can't, because the parent process doesn't exist any more. :) This is a known "problem" with child processes in a program started from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `wait` for the child processes to terminate cleanly. You don't have to call `wait` immediately, but you must call `wait` before the program ends otherwise you have zombie child processes. This works for me and still runs all of the programs in parallel:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct commands
{
    char *cmd[2];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("A program made to understand execvp\n");

    struct commands threeCommands[3];

    pid_t process;
    int child_status;

    threeCommands[0].cmd[0] = "date";
    threeCommands[0].cmd[1] =  NULL;

    threeCommands[1].cmd[0] = "pwd";
    threeCommands[1].cmd[1] =  NULL;

    threeCommands[2].cmd[0] = "cal";
    threeCommands[2].cmd[1] =  NULL;

    for(int i = 0;i <3;i++)
    {
        process = fork();

        if(process == 0)
        {
            execvp(threeCommands[i].cmd[0],threeCommands[i].cmd);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0;i <3;i++)
    {
        wait(&child_status);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The other option is to ignore the `SIGCHLD` signal:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN); // automatically reap child processes
```

Comment: Actually one don't *have* to call `wait` to reap the child processes, even though it's "good manners" to do it. If a child-process becomes an orphan (when its parents exits without waiting for the child to exit) the init process (pid 1) will take over as the parent. A zombie process is a process that have exited but haven't been reaped yes (i.e. the parent haven't called `wait`).